# Accessing Embedded Schema fields via list of Component Links

Tags: templating, razormediator

I have a razor component template which is looping through a list of component links trying to read out fields that come from an embedded schema. The Embedded Schema contains fields like Title, Body, Summary etc. I've read the Razor Mediator documentation which also indicates this is the correct method to adopt.

My code looks like this:

```
@foreach(dynamic item in List)
{
  @item.EmbeddedSchemaName.EmbeddedSchemaFieldName 
}
```

When I try to preview the page I get the typical razor error indicating the field doesn't exist:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Can anyone see a problem here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ensure that `item.EmbeddedSchemaName.EmbeddedSchemaFieldName` is non-null for each item:

```
@foreach(dynamic item in List)
{
    if (item.EmbeddedSchemaName.EmbeddedSchemaFieldName != null)
    {
        @item.EmbeddedSchemaName.EmbeddedSchemaFieldName 
    }
}
```

It may be worth doing the same check for `item.EmbeddedSchemaName`.

From the Razor Mediator documentation:

> The DynamicItemFields class will return null if no property name exists in the ItemFields, or if no value was input for single-valued fields.

This is in contrast to Dreamweaver templating, where you could expect an empty string in return for an empty Component field.

Comment: Thanks Ant, you're correct. I had 5 items in my list of component links, only 2 of which had content in the fields I was trying to render out.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen similar behaviour in other cms that use razor so I would agree to check for nulls unless you can use a Linq extension apply a where clause to your for loop

Shame you have to do a null check in a for loop but hey

Comment: I do not want to discourage you from answering questions here, because your participation on this site  is appreciated, but your answer doesn't really seem to add much to Ant's previously provide answer. You might want to check out the following meta stack exchange on how to write a good answer to questions and take a shot at rewriting your answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: I think I did add to the solution by adding the suggestion of using Linq in the for condition

Comment: I see where a LINQ could handle the null check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882535.aspx. If using the Razor Mediator, do we need anything else to use LINQ expressions? I think all that's needed here is an example.

Comment: Oh, and I also suspect the "tsk tsk" comment about needing to do a null check might look like criticism of either the product (which doesn't apply since this is an extension to SDL Tridion 2011) or the open source Razor Template Mediator itself. Its author, Alex Klock, would be interested in the perspective if he isn't already working on it. :-) Feel free to mention it on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/. To be clear, *this* Razor isn't the same as Razor views on the content delivery side.

Comment: I am sorry if you felt I was "tsking" but I was just attempting to improve the solution isnt that why we are here

Comment: I think that having to do a null check in the for loop is a good thing rather than a drawback.  It is quite common to want to output something different if the field isn't populated and it ensures that the template developer is consciously thinking about the content that they are working with.